# Alphanumeric recursive meeting

Tags: code-challenge

This challenge is about finding the perfect match between your program sourcecode and the output from your program.

Scoring table for the **output**:

```
   Each letters (a-z|A-Z) :   
        `a` or `A`   1 points
        `b` or `B`   2 points
                  ...
        `z` or `Z`  26 points
```

Scoring for the **sourcecode**:

```
   Each non-alphanumeric !(a-z|A-Z|0-9) :    
         3 points
```

**Total** score:

```
     Sourcecode-score * Output-score
```

**Rules**:

1. Your program should take no input (from user, filename, network or anything).
2. **Sourcecode** can be maximum **256** bytes|chars, **Output** can be maximum **384** bytes|chars
3. Your programs output should include its own total score encapsulated within `[]`, for example: `[1024]`.
4. No two neighbouring characters in output or sourcecode can be equal. That also impact the total score variation as it should be part of the output.
5. Constraint, for each output character (=`current char`): 
       The calculated sum of the char-distance to neighbour output char is called: `char-dist`. Non-alpha neighbours always adds 2 to `char-dist`.
       The output characters at `char-dist` pos before the `current char` cannot be equal to the `current char`.
       Calculating `char-dist` is not case sensitive, so the `char-dist` between `A` and `F` is: `5`, and the `char-dist` between `A` and `f` is also: `5`.

Clarification for **rule 5** by example:
If this 3 characters is part of the output: `yZX` then the `char-dist` for `Z` is (1+2)=3. That means 3 character pos before that `Z` there cannot be another `Z` or `z` in the output. Positions does not wrap around edges of the output.

Example non-valid output-part:

`XYZYXW` - here the calculated `char-dist` for the second `Y` from left is: `(1+1)=2`, and therefor the first `Y` from left cannot be two char pos before.

Example valid output-part:

`XYZYWX` - here the calculated `char-dist` for the second `Y` from left is: `(1+2)=3` => the first `Y` from left is 2 positions away = valid.

***Example valid answers:***

I think I should sum this challenge up by giving some simple example valid answers:

**Javascript** (code: 34, output: 18) - Total score: `(24*246)=5904`

```
Sourcecode:    console.log("OPQRSTUVWXYZ[5904]");
Output:        OPQRSTUVWXYZ[5904]
```

**Golfscript** (code: 32, output: 32) - Total score: `(39*491)=19149`

```
Sourcecode:    '[19149]' 2{'NPQRSTUVWXYZ'}* 'A'
Output:        [19149]NPQRSTUVWXYZNPQRSTUVWXYZA
```

This is code-challenge, best total score wins! Good luck, have fun!

Comment: Do whitespaces count 3 towards my sourcecode scoring?

Comment: Yes, whitespace counts as non-alphanumeric => 3 points each

Comment: Rule 4 was meant to be case insensitive, for example: Zz or Aa is not allowed in sourecode or output